# estoy intentando hacer un bot para whatsapp usando selenium, que no me esta enviando los mensajes

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, bot, whatsapp-web

estoy intentando hacer un bot para whatsapp usando selenium, despues de leer un archivo xlsx tomar los numero de telefono, y clasificarlos por tipo para enviar los diferentes mensajes, accede a whatsapp web mediante chromedrive, accede al numero, crea el mensaje, pero al final no los envia, adjunto el codigo de la funcion que deberia hacer este proceso.

cualquier orientacion sera bienvenida.
Saludos

```
def enviar_mensajes():
    contenido = contenido_texto.get('1.0', tk.END)
    lineas = contenido.split('\n')
    
    for linea in lineas[1:]:
        datos = linea.split('\t')
        if len(datos) >= 3:
            idpais = datos[1]
            telefono = datos[2]
            tipo = datos[4]
            mensaje = f'Ola {idpais}{telefono} esto es una prueba para {tipo}. Favor enviar OK si es posible'
            link_mensaje_whatsapp = f'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={idpais}{telefono}&text={quote(mensaje)}'
            
            try:
                if not navegador:
                    print("Por favor, abre WhatsApp primero.")
                    return
                
                navegador.get(link_mensaje_whatsapp)
                time.sleep(10)
                WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.input-container")))
                campo_mensaje = navegador.find_element_by_css_selector('div.input-container')
                time.sleep(10)
                campo_mensaje.send_keys(mensaje)
                time.sleep(10)
                navegador.find_element_by_css_selector('#main > footer > div._2lSWV._3cjY2.copyable-area > div > span:nth-child(2) > div > div._1VZX7 > div._2xy_p._3XKXx > button > span').click()
                time.sleep(15)  # Espera 5 segundos antes de enviar el siguiente mensaje
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'No fue posible enviar mensaje para {idpais}{telefono}: {str(e)}')
```

Comment: No te recomiendo utilizar selenium y tkinter en el mismo código ya que va a acabar tardando mucho y vas a tener que esperar bastante. Para este programa no necesitas renderizar la página completa (cosa que hace selenium), simplemente necesitas hacer una petición 'POST'. Te sugiero que indagues sobre la api de whatsapp (creo que tiene una) y utilices requests para realizar dicha solicitud. ¡Mucha suerte!

Comment: Efectivamente, usar selenium para usar un whatsapp web es una locura cuando tienes una API preciosa que sirve para lo mismo pero está diseñada para ser usada precisamente mediante código...